# How do i rename and move all .srt files in multiple sub folders to main folder?

Tags: file-management, files

[image: These are multiple .srt files in every folder.]

How do I rename the .srt files inside these folders and move them to main folder so that I can transfer it on USB drive to watch on TV

Comment: Use [`find`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) and [`mv`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1.html) on Termux.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.